# Why should I used dialogflow() over actionssdk() in Actions on Google Nodejs client Library

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

Based on the V1 to V2 Node.js Client Library [Migration guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration) there are two ways of listening to conversations

so the following code from V1

```
const {DialogflowApp } = require('actions-on-google');

const actionMap = new Map();

actionMap.set('input.welcome', app => {   app.ask('How are you?'); });

...
```

can be replaced with either the dialogflow module

```
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {   conv.ask('How are you?'); });
```

or Actions SDK module

```
const { actionssdk } = require('actions-on-google');
const app = actionssdk();

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', conv => {   conv.ask('How are you?'); });
```

In the first case (dialogflow) you recongize the Intent by its name but at the second (actionSdk) you recognize it from the actions name.

Why should I use one over the other and what are the benefits and limitations of each method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both libraries will deliver the transcription of what the user of your Action has said. Which library you use depends on how you intend to understand the text - to make sense of it and react accordingly. If you plan to parse it in a bespoke manner or if you have your own natural language processor (aka NLP/NLU) you use the Actions SDK. If you don't you can use Dialog Flow as the NLP and its library.